# Shortest path with dynamic programming

Tags: c, dynamic-programming

I don't want the answer to this problem, I just need a nudge in the right direction.

> Given an undirected graph `G` having `N` (`1<N<=1000`) vertices and positive weights. Find the shortest path from vertex `1` to vertex `N`, or state that such path doesn’t exist.
>
> Hint: At each step, among the vertices which weren’t yet checked and for which a path from vertex `1` was found, take the one which has the shortest path, from vertex `1` to it, yet found.

First I have to define a state. This is what I said:

> The state is the solution for vertex `i`, where `i <= N`. Smaller state would be the solution for `j`, where `j<i`. To find state `i`, we need to find all smaller states `j` (`j<i`). Having found the shortest path to `i`, we can easily find the next state - the solution for `i+1`.

I took this from a different problem and just replaced variable names and some words because it sounded applicable to this one.

I have to write a program for the solution, but I don't know how to start. Here are my questions:

1. Is my definition of the state correct?
2. Moreover, since this is an undirected graph, and each vertex is bidirectional, will the weights be passed in as a multidimensional array (i.e `int W[N][2]`) where `W[N][0]` is the weight of one vertex and `W[N][1]` the weight of the other?
3. How do I represent the shortest path? Is it the number of paths taken, the sum of all the weights of the paths taken, or is it an array of all the weights of the paths taken?

Comment: This sounds like the kind of problem where the input format is specified for you. But I didn't see anything that related the number of edges and the number of vertices. So I don't think you can assume that N relates to the number of total vertices in the graph.

Comment: Also, I don't think your state is correct. If you require a solution for smaller i, then you start with a solution for 1. And since the problem is to get from 1 to N, you must be done?

Comment: @AustinHastings I got it from the first practice problem here - https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/dynamic-programming-from-novice-to-advanced/

Comment: Sure. But I think that when you get to 1 you're done. So maybe it should be reversed?

Comment: Okay I'll try to reverse it. Now what about question #2, and #3?

Comment: This is not related in any way to C.  It may be more related to algorithms, such as _[this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm)_.  In any case, you might consider editing your post to remove the C tag, and add another that better describes the genre of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered All-Pairs Shortest Paths algorithms? The **Floyd-Warshall algorithm** for example sounds as a possible solution for your problem.

Floyd-Warshall algorithm is a dynamic programing algorithm. Also Floyd-Warshal algorithm supports directed graphs hence also undirected.

Floyd-Warshall has a time complexity of Θ(|V|^3) and space complexity of Θ(|V|^2)

Wikipedia Link
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm

C implementation
http://www.c-program-example.com/2011/10/c-program-to-implement-warshalls.html

Finding the path can be left as an exercise
This link has an example of how its done but you will need to translate it to C. You can find it under Matrix of Predecessors
http://www.programming-algorithms.net/article/45708/Floyd-Warshall-algorithm

This seems as a nice visual representation of the algorithm
https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/Floyd.html

Another approach would be the **Bellman Ford algorithm**. This is not an all pairs shortest path, instead it computes the shortest path from a single point to all other vertices.

Bellman-Ford algorithm is a dynamic programing algorithm. Also Bellman-Ford algorithm supports weighted directed graphs hence also undirected.

Bellman-Ford has a time complexity of Θ(|V||E|) and space complexity of Θ(|V|)

Wikipedia Link
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm

C implementation
http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~cs57/Project/bellman-ford.c

In your case (assuming the space complexity is not an issue here) choosing between the two would mainly depend on the number of vertices compared to the number of edges. Generally if |E| is much greater than (|V|^2) then you should probably go with Warshall-Floyd otherwise if (|V|^2) is much greater than |E| you should probably go with Bellman-Ford.