# Creating a graph from a txt file in C

Tags: c, parsing, graph

I have a txt file, which contains groups of 3 elements in each line (2 strings for vertices and 1 integer for edge), which i want to use as input to create an adjacency list for a graph.

The txt file is as so: "string1 string2 34" and the elements are separated by tabs.

I've tried for starters trying to read from the file, using fgets , and managed to print the elements, but i'm stuck as to how i can parse them and store them. Any ideas?

Comment: fscanf see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3p.html

Comment: What did you try? Are you stuck reading the two strings? Or something else?

Comment: @user253751 I tried `while(!feof(fp)){
        
        fgets(buff, 40, fp);
        puts(buff);
    }`                              I also tried using many char arrays for storing the elements using `fscanf` , like so:   `while(!feof(fp)){
    fscanf(fp, "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s", str1, str2, str3, str4, str5, str6);
    }
    printf(str1, str2, str3, str4, str5, str6);`

Comment: Have you ever parsed a file before?

Comment: Not in C. I think I may have separated elements from lists like this in Python, but as far as I remember, it was way easier

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What does the number mean? Is it a label? A weight? A sequence number? ...? And what's the data structure you want to create?

Comment: @rici I want to create a graph using an adjacency list. The number is sort of representing a distance between the place "string1" and the place "string2". I have a txt file with a bunch of groups of 3 of these, and I want to create a graph out of them and use Bellman Ford to find the sortest path from specific sources out of the list.

Comment: Why do you want to do this on C, exactly? It's not a an easy exercise for a first C program. The parsing is easy, but that's just a small part of the infrastructure. You're going to have to implement a graph structure, and then you'll need some kind of associative mapping to convert the strings into references to nodes in that graph. If you aren't comfortable with dynamic memory allocation, everything is even more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A complete solution can be found at https://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2017/06/bellman-ford-algorithm-in-c-and-c.html

The Bellman-Ford algorithm in C is also discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/36831569/18980756.

Nevertheless, some code based on your input to put the elements into a dynamically allocated linked list:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct FORM {
    char *vertice_one;
    char *vertice_two;
    int weight;
    struct FORM *next;
} FORM;

int main() {
    int err = 0; // error indicator

    // helper to store temporarily store read values
    char s1[256], s2[256]; 
    int w;

    FORM *firstEntry = NULL; // root element for the list

    FILE *file = fopen("forms.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL) goto cleanup;

    // read three line elements into variables
    while (fscanf(file, "%s%s%d\n", &s1[0], &s2[0], &w) == 3) {
        // print read elements for debugging purposes
        printf("read: %s-%s-%d\n", s1, s2, w);

        // dynamically allocate memory to store the read values
        FORM *newEntry = malloc(sizeof *newEntry);
        if (newEntry == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error - Not enough memory!");
            err = 1;
            goto cleanup;
        }

        char *vert1 = malloc(strlen(&s1[0]) + 1);
        char *vert2 = malloc(strlen(&s2[0]) + 1);
        if (vert1 == NULL || vert2 == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error - Not enough memory!");
            err = 1;
            goto cleanup;
        }
        memcpy(vert1, &s1[0], strlen(&s1[0]) + 1);
        memcpy(vert2, &s2[0], strlen(&s2[0]) + 1);

        newEntry->vertice_one = vert1;
        newEntry->vertice_two = vert2;
        newEntry->weight = w;

        // put new entry to front a linked list
        newEntry->next = firstEntry;
        firstEntry = newEntry;
    }

    FORM *p = firstEntry;
    while(p != NULL) {
        printf("%s\t%s\t%d\n", p->vertice_one, p->vertice_two, p->weight);
        p = p->next;
    }

    FORM *q;
cleanup:
    q = firstEntry;
    while(q != NULL) {
        FORM *entry = q;
        q = q->next;
        if (entry->vertice_one != NULL) free(entry->vertice_one);
        if (entry->vertice_two != NULL) free(entry->vertice_two);
        free(entry);
    }

    if (file != NULL) {
        fclose(file);
    }

    return err;
}
```

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra graph.c
$ ./a.out                  
read: vert1-vert2-1
read: vert3-vert4-2
vert3   vert4   2
vert1   vert2   1
$
```

Now you are in C land and can start thinking about how you want to work with the data read.

I guess

- `FORM` should be named `EDGE`
- `vertex_one` should be named `source`
- `vertex_two` should be named `destination`
- `weight` remains `weight`

You could avoid the dynamic allocation if you define arrays which are large enough to hold the data from the file.